Есть ошибки в обособлении пояснительной конструкции?
Из современной художественной литературы:
– Ладно. Пошли поглядим что за краля.
Он подошел к англичанке, за всё время ни разу не шевельнувшейся, и без церемоний откинул кисею.
Увидев вблизи два заросших бородою лица – одно щекастое и пожилое, другое – худое и еще не старое, Мэри зажмурилась. Ей хотелось поскорей пробудиться от ужасного сна.
Вызывают сомнение два тире. По какому правилу обособляется оборот? Возможны ли другие решения?
